# PHP Session declare in POSTMAN

Tags: php, session, postman, session-cookies

I am testing the PHP application, on my implementation there is a checking if the session userID that I set is existing in session before proceeding in any transaction

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
   $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
```

how can I set this session in postman? cause im testing the app in postman.

Comment: The session ID is stored in a cookie, so configure postman to store and forward cookies.